# Easier solution to searching files in a directory

Tags: c, algorithm, search, file-io, readdir

I'm curious to learn other possible solutions to this problem statement.

I've a directory where the files are already sorted based on file creation time i.e,
latest file comes first and the oldest file would be at the last. And my goal is to
grab the files that were created between a specified interval. Input would be a
'start time' (like 14:00:00) and 'end time', (like 13:00:00) and thus I've to grab
the files that were created between 'start time' and 'end time' and copy to a different
folder.

My Design:
First, name the files with 'time stamp' of their creation time and then compare the each file's name with the 'start time' and 'end time' to identify the required range of files.

So, my logic would looks something like this,

```
while (!endOfDirectory && endFileNotFound)
{
    if(fileName > 'start time') && (fileName < 'end time')
    {
        copyTo(diff/Folder);
        //Executes till all the required files are copied
    }
    //This is to stop searching once the required files are obtained.
    if(fileName older than start time) 
    {
        endFileNotFound = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is looking through each file one by one to find the 'start file' of the range and thus involves using readdir(dir). Is there a better way to identify the start file and end file without doing readdir() and jumping straight to the start file.?

Comment: You have more problem than that, because few (if any) of the big and common filesystems are really ordered. All ordering of file listings are done by the applications doing the listing, it's not inherent in the filesystem itself. So to find all files in a directory that fulfills some criteria, you must really read the information for all the files in that directory.

Comment: @OznOg I am looking for better solutions than what I have. I think that by using readdir(), I'll have to read each and every file name.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. I'm writing this for an embedded application that is running QNX. I thought this detail might not be required. The files are created by another process.

Comment: @OznOg please do suggest some links. I googled and I'm not aware of how 'Graphs' can be applied here. If you suggest, I will surely read it.

Comment: It does not matter which part of the system does the loop, your application or a system function: A directory is commonly just some kind of array, and it needs to visit each member to test for the time. -- Which file system does your system use? -- If your application can start before the "start time", you could try to hook into some "new file generated" event, and watch the file system.

Comment: A concrete case of what @thebusybee is refering to: The "new file generated" hook is the `IN_CREATE` event in the [inotify API](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)

Comment: @thebusybee. Thanks for replying. Such an event wouldn't be helpful actually in my case because the application wouldn't know the 'start and end time' in prior. It is real time and keeps changing. And the file is system in QNX File system. @ wsdookadr, thanks for pointing out the API.

Comment: Can your application start upfront, and when a new set of times "arrives", be notified of this set? -- What is the (estimated) number of files in that directory, and how many are probably to be copied?

Comment: The application will be running the entire time (even before the request arrives). But the arrived request can only ask for the files that are already present in the directory meaning the 'start' and 'end time' would be pointing to 'past' time. There are about 200 files in the directory and I might be only copying around 8-10 files (estimated).